# Mongodb add autoincrement id to existing records

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-documentdb

I have added one extra field called serial to my questions collections.
I am using below query to update serial number as auto increment number.
This query is working in my local

```
db.questions.aggregate([ { $setWindowFields: { sortBy: { _id: 1 }, output: { serial: { $sum: 1, window: { documents: ["unbounded", "current"] } } } } }, { $merge: { into: "questions" } }])
```

My production dataabase is in aws documnent db. which is 4.0.0 so probably  $setWindowFields doesn't support there.
I am getting below error

```
  rs0:PRIMARY> db.questions.aggregate([ { $setWindowFields: { sortBy: { _id: 1 }, output: { serial: { $sum: 1, window: { documents: ["unbounded", "current"] } } } } }, { $merge: { into: "questions" } }])
  assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 40324,
    "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$setWindowFields'",
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1684228959, 1)
  } : aggregate failed
  _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
  doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
  assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:403:5
  DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:260:9
  DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1212:12
  @(shell):1:1

  2023-05-16T09:22:39.880+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 40324,
    "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$setWindowFields'",
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1684228959, 1)
  } : aggregate failed :
  _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
  doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
  assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:403:5
  DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:260:9
  DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1212:12
  @(shell):1:1
```

Please check how to solve this.

Comment: Which version of documentdb you have ?

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to answer since I've never used AWS DocumentDB and this aggregation pipeline is ugly, but perhaps it might work.

```js
db.questions.aggregate([
  {"$sort": {"_id": 1}},
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "newRoots": {"$push": "$_id"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "newRoots": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {"$range": [0, {"$size": "$newRoots"}]},
          "as": "serial",
          "in": {
            "_id": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$newRoots", "$$serial"]},
            "serial": {"$add": ["$$serial", 1]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$newRoots"},
  {"$replaceWith": "$newRoots"},
  {"$merge": "questions"}
])
```